# 403 forbidden after wordpress custom field update

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, http-status-code-403

I was looking for an answer to my problem, but I couldn't find any answer which solves my case.

I have created a custom field via Pods in Wordpress , in which I insert through TinyMCE editor html code . When the generated code contains the word "style" (eg. `<span style="text-align:center">`) I get 403 forbidden error status after update . When the generated code doesn't contains style, but other html attributes (e.g just `<strong>` or `<center>` ) everything works fine. This started to happens since few last days . I have tried to deactivate the plug and use the default WYSIWYG but nothing changed.
Any idea ?

Comment: share your code, so we can figure this out to help you, Also, have you tried ACF? try to ACF to see if you get the same issue, another tip
try to use some style.css <span class="my-class"> go to apparence -> Customize -> Additional CSS ent use the class that you created in span  .my-class{ text-align:center; }

Comment: <p><span style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;color:#00ffbf">
text blah blah
</span></p> . When I press update button then 403 forbidden error.

Unfortunately this field is used by several users who can't create his own css classes . Also this happens in every wordpress admin menu option with custom fields which host html codes.